# How to override the standard button for specific record type?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom object called Service__c . 
When creating "New" Service Record, for the 'RFLEET_Option_OPP' record type only I want to override the standard Page. For other Record types the Standard Page remains.
Here my code:

```
Apex:
public class Demo_EXT{
String sRetURL = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('sRetURL');
String strRecordId;
public String strDevName;

public Demo_EXT(ApexPages.StandardController std) {

    strRecordId = std.getId();
    //system.debug('>>>>>>>>sRecordId '+strRecordId);

}

public PageReference urlRedirect() {
    String strServiceRecType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');
    system.debug('>>>>>>>>strServiceRecType '+strServiceRecType );
    if (strRecordId == null && strServiceRecType != null){
         strDevName='';
        try {
           strDevName= [Select Id, Name, DeveloperName from Recordtype WHERE SObjectType = 'Service__c'  and Id = :strServiceRecType ].DeveloperName;   
            system.debug('>>>>>>>>strDevName'+strDevName);      
        }catch (QueryException e){
                System.debug('Error' + e);
        }

       if (strDevName== 'RFLEET_Option_OPP'){
           system.debug('>>>>>>>>Inside if strDevName'+strDevName);
         return new PageReference('/apex/DemoVF?RecordType='+strServiceRecType );

        }
        else {
            system.debug('>>>>>>>>Inside else'+strDevName);
            return new PageReference('/a0G/e?sRetURL=%2Fa0G%2Fo&RecordType=012580000000PIb&ent=Service__c&nooverride=1');

        }

    } 

     return null;
  }


}

VF:

<apex:page standardcontroller="Service__c"  extensions="Demo_EXT" action="{!urlRedirect}">
<apex:messages />
    <apex:sectionheader title="{!$ObjectType.Service__c.label} Edit" subtitle="{!IF(ISNULL(Service__c.Name), 'New Service',Service__c.Name)}"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock mode="edit" title="{!$ObjectType.Service__c.label} Edit">
            <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="true" columns="2">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.Name}"/>
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Service__c.OwnerId}"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.Service_Type__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.CurrencyIsoCode}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.CB_Services_Repository__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.Price_HT__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.CB_Options_repository__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.Customer_Sales_Price_HT__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.Code__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.Quantity__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.Label__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                </apex:pageblocksection>
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Order Car Set" showheader="true" columns="2">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Service__c.Car_Set__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                </apex:pageblocksection>
                <apex:pageblocksection title="System Information" showheader="true" columns="2">
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Service__c.RecordTypeId}"/>
                </apex:pageblocksection>


                  </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>

Issue am facing:
```

When I choose the  record type, other than "RFLEET_Option_OPP" It redirects to the Standard Page. Its working fine. But when I click the "RFLEET_Option_OPP" record type it redirects to the Vf page with below error

> Visual force Error Cyclical server-side forwards detected:
>   /apex/DemoVF?RecordTypeid=012580000000PIb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Way I found Use action to call a method before loading your VF page completely

```
<apex:page action="{!checkRecordType}">
```

in you class check

current record recordTypeId. If recordType is different Just redirect to standard page using record Id and `nooverride=1`

```
public pagereference  checkRecordType(){
  If(objCustomobjectRecordType != 'your recordTypeId')
  {
        return new PageReference('/'+objCustomobject.Id+'nooverride=1');
  }
}
```

This way to view the standard detail page of the record.

---

For New button

You can follow the same steps as above

but in checkRecordType method Just redirect to standard edit page

```
public pagereference  checkRecordType(){
      If(objCustomobjectRecordType != 'your recordTypeId')
      {
            return new PageReference('/003/e?nooverride=1');
      }
    }
```

Here Just an example I am using `003` for contact. you can use your custom object prefix

You can get the Custom object prefix using

```
system.debug('========='+ OBJECTAPINAME.sobjecttype.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());
```

Run this code in developer console and get the custom object prefix.