# Can an Aura action override redirect to the standard lightning action?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I need to override the New Case standard action with a custom Lightning (Aura) component, but I only need to do so for some record types (3 of 6).  Is it possible within a Lightning Component to redirect to the standard action?  So for example:

1. Create New Case Action Override component, implement `lightning:actionOverride` and `lightning:hasPageReference`.
2. Override Case's New action to use my new component, but do NOT check the "skip record type selection" box.
3. System displays record type selection, shows my component.
4. My component [gets selected record type using page ref info as outlined here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/227943/149).
5. If the record type does not need the custom component override, component redirects to the standard New Case LEX UI with the record type set.
6. Otherwise, component displays and accepts input as normal.

Step 5 is the question.  In VF, I'd add an `action` param to the `apex:page` to check the recordTypeId and redirect using classic URls, [as in this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/114253/149).  Is this possible in LEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [`force:createRecord`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation) event here and set the `recordTypeId` attribute to present the standard create screen for a particular record type.

Sample code would look like:

```
var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
createRecordEvent.setParams({
    "entityApiName": "Case",
    "recordTypeId" : "xxxxxxx"
});
createRecordEvent.fire();
```

Comment: Good solution. I would add that OP could check a value and determine if they want to create a record or send to a custom component. I used this to control the record type because my users tend to never pick the correct one.